# CucumberJS and Selenium Webdriver - Run same steps with different inputs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm starting with Cucumber and Selenium.

I've created a test case where selenium runs a form and inputs default values, and clicks on default buttons, let's call this `test case 1`, but now I need `test case 2`, where I should run same steps, but with different inputs, imagine this:

I have a form where I have a selection, if the user is a **Male** or **Female**, depending on the button clicked, my form changes, so if I choose **Male**, I get for example an input asking if I'm "tall" (just an example), but if I choose **Female**, I get an input asking if "I have a boyfriend". Depending on my journey on the form the final result is different, taking this into account:

How could I create multiple test cases, without repeating code, that would test each option?

Example:

```
Test case A: Male Input

Test case B: Female Input
```

I need Test case A to finish the form, and next execute Test Case B, remember that my form has inputs that are the same in both scenarios, so I will have to use multiple times the same:

```
Scenario A:
  Given I have to choose Male or Female
  When I click ('one of them')
  Then I will click other stuff
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Scenario Outline is something best suits your scenario.

```
Scenario Outline: Validate Selection
  Given I am in the required page
  When I selection <choice> from the option
  Then I will click other stuff

Examples:
|choice|
|Male  |
|Female|
```

Best example from the docs here. [Link](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/)

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |    12 |   5 |    7 |
    |    20 |   5 |   15 |
```